# Tengo un problema con cors, al insertar un usuario de angular a una api rest php

Tags: php, angular, typescript, cors

Tengo una api rest php en la cual defino las funciones y los métodos para las solicitudes del cliente que es angular en este caso, se supone que tengo el código para que no salga lo de las cors pero me sigue saliendo igualmente, así que les muestro el código, para ver si ustedes ven algo que yo no estoy viendo.

Este es el modelo de cliente.php, donde tengo las funciones que hacen el crud

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);
require_once "connection/conexion.php";

class Cliente {

    function insert($nombre, $apellido,  $dni, $email,$movil)
    {
        try {
            $consultaInsertar = "INSERT INTO 
            clientes (nombre,apellido,dni,email,movil)
             VALUES (:nombre,:apellido,:dni,:email,:movil)";
            $conexion = new ConexionBD();
            $stmt = $conexion::Conexion()->prepare($consultaInsertar);
            $stmt->bindParam(':nombre', $nombre);
            $stmt->bindParam(':apellido', $apellido);
            $stmt->bindParam(':movil', $movil);
            $stmt->bindParam(':dni', $dni);
            $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
            $stmt->execute();
    
            return true;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            throw new Exception("No se pudo insertar el registro en la tabla de clientes: " . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    function getAll():array {
        $consulta = "SELECT * FROM clientes";
        $datos = $this->sentenciaOtenerTodosValores($consulta);
        return $datos;
    }

    function getWhere($id){
        $consulta = "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE id=:id";
        $conexion = new ConexionBD();
        $query = $conexion::Conexion()->prepare($consulta);
        $query->bindParam(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->execute();
        $datos = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $datos;
    }

    function sentenciaOtenerTodosValores($consulta){
        $conexion = new ConexionBD();
        $datos = $conexion::consulta($consulta)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
       return $datos;
    }

    function delete($id){
        $consulta = "DELETE FROM clientes WHERE id= :id";
        $conexion = new ConexionBD();

        $query = $conexion::Conexion()->prepare($consulta);
        $query->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        if ($query->execute()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    function update($id,$nombre, $apellido, $dni, $email,$movil){
        $consulta = "UPDATE clientes SET NOMBRE = :nombre , APELLIDO = :apellido,
         DNI = :dni, EMAIL = :email, MOVIL=:movil WHERE ID = :id";
        $conexion = new ConexionBD();

        $stmt = $conexion::Conexion()->prepare($consulta);
        $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
        $stmt->bindParam(':nombre', $nombre);
        $stmt->bindParam(':apellido', $apellido);
        $stmt->bindParam(':movil', $movil);
        $stmt->bindParam(':dni', $dni);
        $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
        

        if($stmt->execute()){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    function existeCliente($dni) {
        $sql="SELECT * FROM clientes Where clientes.dni='$dni'";
        $conexion = new ConexionBD();
        $query = $conexion::Conexion()->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute();
        //Comprobamos si el dato dado por parametro existe en la bbdd
       $count=$query->fetch();
       return($count);
    }
}
```

Luego aquí es donde defino los métodos post,put,delete y get, que llaman a esas funciones para las solicitudes de angular, en mi caso estoy insertando un cliente, si podéis ver, tengo el código de las cors, puesto y aún así me sigue saliendo el error que esta más abajo.

```
<?php
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200");
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type");
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-Key, Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method");

 require_once "models/cliente.php";

 $clientes = new Cliente();

switch ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
case 'GET':
    if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
        echo json_encode($clientes->getWhere($_GET['id']));
    } else {
        echo json_encode($clientes->getAll());
    }
    break;

case 'POST':
    $datos = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
    if ($datos != NULL) {
        // Primero verificamos si el cliente ya existe en la base de datos
        $cliente_existente = $clientes->existeCliente($datos->dni);
        if ($cliente_existente) {
            // Si el cliente ya existe, devolvemos un error
            http_response_code(409);
            echo json_encode(array("mensaje" => "El cliente ya existe en la base de datos"));
        } else {
            $nombre = $datos->nombre;
            $apellido = $datos->apellido;
            $movil = $datos->movil;
            $dni = $datos->dni;
            $email = $datos->email;
            if ($clientes->insert($nombre, $apellido,  $dni, $email, $movil)) {
                http_response_code(200);
            } else {
                http_response_code(500);
                echo json_encode(array("mensaje" => "No se pudo insertar el cliente en la base de datos"));
            }
        }
    } else {
        http_response_code(400);
        echo json_encode(array("mensaje" => "Los datos enviados no son válidos"));
    }
    break;



case 'PUT':
    $datos = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
    if ($datos != NULL) {
        $id = $datos->id;
        $nombre = $datos->nombre;
        $apellido = $datos->apellido;
        $movil = $datos->movil;
        $dni = $datos->dni;
        $email = $datos->email;
        if ($clientes->update($id, $nombre, $apellido, $dni, $email, $movil)) {
            http_response_code(200);
        } //end if
        else {
            http_response_code(400);
        } //end else
    } //end if
    else {
        http_response_code(405);
    } //end else
    break;

case 'DELETE':
    if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
        if ($clientes->delete($_GET['id'])) {
            http_response_code(200);
        } //end if
        else {
            http_response_code(400);
        } //end else
    } //end if 
    else {
        http_response_code(405);
    } //end else
    break;

default:
    http_response_code(405);
    break;
}//end while
```

Luego en angular, en el servicio, tengo el código siguiente:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Cliente } from 'src/app/modelos/cliente/cliente.models';

@Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root'
 })
 export class ClienteService {
 private apiUrl = 'http://localhost/apirestphp/apiclientes.php';

 constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getClientes(): Observable<Cliente[]> {
    return this.http.get<Cliente[]>(`${this.apiUrl}`);
  }

   getClientesID(id:number): Observable<Cliente[]> {
     return this.http.get<Cliente[]>(`${this.apiUrl}?id=${id}`);
   }
  deleteClientesID(id:number): Observable<Cliente[]> {
     return this.http.delete<Cliente[]>(`${this.apiUrl}?id=${id}`);
   }
  insertClientes(cliente: Cliente): Observable<Cliente[]> {
     return this.http.post<Cliente[]>(`${this.apiUrl}/`,cliente);
   }

   editarClientes(cliente: Cliente): Observable<Cliente[]> {
      return this.http.put<Cliente[]>(`${this.apiUrl}/`,JSON.stringify(cliente));
   }

 }
```

En la interface de cliente defino las variables y su tipo, para guardarlas, posteriormente, el código de la interface seria este:

```
export interface Cliente{
id: number;
nombre:string;
apellido:string;
dni:string;
email:string;
movil:number;
}
```

En el componente donde tengo hago el insertar, que tengo el formulario que recoge los campos verificados, tengo el siguiente código:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ClienteService } from 'src/app/Servicios/clientes/cliente.service';
import { RolesService } from 'src/app/Servicios/rol/roles.service';
import { UsuariosService } from 'src/app/Servicios/usuario/usuarios.service';
import { Cliente } from 'src/app/modelos/cliente/cliente.models';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-crear-cliente',
  templateUrl: './crear-cliente.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./crear-cliente.component.scss']
 })
 export class CrearClienteComponent implements OnInit {
 cliente:Cliente[]=[];
 form!: FormGroup;

 // CONSTRUCTOR
 constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
 private _clienteService:ClienteService, 
 private http: HttpClient) {}

 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
    nombre: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/)]],
    apellido: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/)]],
    dni: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^\d{8}[A-Z]$/i
    )]],
    email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
   movil: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^\d{9}$/)]],
   });
  }

  agregarCliente(): void {
    if (this.form.valid) {
    const cliente: Cliente = this.form.value;
    console.log(cliente);
    this._clienteService.insertClientes(cliente).subscribe(() => {
       console.log('Cliente agregado correctamente');
       // resetear el formulario
       this.form.reset();
     }, (error) => {
     console.error(error);
     });
    } else {
      console.log('Formulario inválido');
    }
  }
}
```

El error que me esta dando, entiendo que esta bloqueando la solicitud , porque las cors están bloqueándolas, pero si tengo definido en las cors los métodos, y el localhost, no me tendría porque salir, no entiendo, este es el mensaje de error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desde postman con la url, si me inserta los datos

Comment: Creo que el problema viene de Angular, los frameworks o librerías de front como axios llevan su propia configuración de CORS, con independencia del backend.
Para saber más sobre tu error puedes consultar https://fjmduran.com/blog/proxy-cors-angular, una búsqueda "problemas de CORS Angular" también puede ayudarte.

Comment: Algo que te puede servir para identificar dónde está el problema es desactivar los CORS en el navegador. Si con los CORS desactivados la petición funciona bien entonces es problema de backend. Aquí puedes ver algunos comandos para iniciar el navegador sin CORS https://alfilatov.com/posts/run-chrome-without-cors/

Comment: nada amigos no funciona